# Are questions like "App X is great, are there other apps like it?" appropriate?

Tags: discussion, scope, questions

If you have some app for something that you like and are looking for other similar apps, is that an appropriate question?

Answer (score 2):

This is still a list of X question, just rephrased. Consider it as a cooking.se question: 'I like macaroni and cheese, what are some other macaroni and cheese recipes?' It invites poor answers that have a subjective basis (especially here where it would often be localized to a particular handset).

Comment: I agree with your example, but wouldn't the following be acceptable on cooking.se: "I love mac & cheese, but my recipe is missing something.  What would make this better?"  ...I think what our bigger question here is: is this site a place to discover new apps, or do we need to direct those questions elsewhere?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to say that this depends on how specific it is.  At the least, it should be community wiki.  If it isn't specific enough, then it should be closed.

Answer (score 1):

My opinion: If the question specifies *how* an app would be "like" X, as in providing a list of required features/constraints, then that's OK.

But in that case, you don't really need the "App X" in there.  I suppose it doesn't *hurt*, but you could just say "I'm looking for an app with these 10 features."

Unless these questions are significantly constrained, there's no appreciable difference between them and [What X app should I get?](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/are-what-apps-should-i-get-questions-appropriate) questions.  I'd at least be suspicious of any and all questions taking this format, as they are likely to be treated as polls.