# Voting to close a "list" or "favorite" question - Which reason should I select?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

[This answer](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/are-what-apps-should-i-get-questions-appropriate/29#29) here on meta points out a number of questions asking for a list of apps or "your favorite *X* app" which should probably be closed due to their subjective/unanswerable nature.

When I vote to close a question like these, which reason is the right one to use: "Not a question", "Subjective", or "Off-topic"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, my first tumbleweed badge.  Wohoo!

I guess I'm going with "Not a question"

Comment: Not a question sounds fine to me

Answer (score 1):

The choices have changed. I suggest that the correct reason is now "Not Constructive".

> As it currently stands, this question is not a good fit for our Q&A format. We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or specific expertise, but this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion. If you feel that this question can be improved and possibly reopened, see the FAQ for guidance.